# WebApi file download has frozen the browser for the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using WebAPI for downloading a `.pdf` file like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadFile(string id, bool attachment = true)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;

    try
    {
        MyService service = new MyService();
        var bytes = await service.DownloadFileAsync(id);

        if (bytes != null)
        {
            result = GetBinaryFile(personalDocument, string.Format("{0}.pdf", id), attachment);
        }
        else
        {
            result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) { ReasonPhrase = "ServerError" });
    }

    return result;
}

private HttpResponseMessage GetBinaryFile(byte[] bytes, string fileName, bool attachment)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   // result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes));
    //result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");

    if (attachment)
    {
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    }

    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    return result;
}
```

The issue is: when I download file for the first time it freezes the browser, and cannot perform anything. But after a refresh of the page, every time the file download is successful.

I tried to use `ByteArrayContent` or `StreamContent` but same thing happens. I also tried to use `MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream")` or `MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf")`, but again - the same issue occurred.

So I find that the problem is

```
if (attachment)
{
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
}
```

If I set attachment to be true it set `ContentDisposition` to be `ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")` (it is for download only)

If I set attachment to be false it open the file immediately and doesn't freeze the browser..

Any idea? Thanks!